# Thunderbird double message

Tags: email, thunderbird

Every time I get an email to my gmail account in Thunderbird, I get two notifications for the same message. The same message appears twice, once in my inbox and once in my "All Mail" folder.

This wouldn't be a problem if "All mail"'s read messages synced with the inbox. But to make the unread messages go away in "All Mail", I have to read the message twice: once in the inbox and once in "All Mail."

Does anyone have a fix for this problem, or am I just doing it wrong?

Also, if it matters, I use Thunderbird 3.1.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is resynchronize that folder which does not happen automatically.

For my gmail account in TBird, I have "all mail" for offline use disabled. So when I access "All Mail" while connected to the Internet, it shows me the updated folder.

To achieve this use the following steps:

Select the account->`Tools`->`Account Settings`->`Synchronization and Storage`->`Message Synchronization`->`Advanced`->Uncheck "All folders" for that account

Once you do that, it will not download all the messages in all mail automatically. This will result in updating of the folder when you select it in thunderbird and hence getting the updated email read/unread list.

Hope this helps